# Using a Userform to copy a certain graph. What is missing?

Tags: excel, vba

The user will click on a button. Then the UserForm opens, there he will choose the type of graph he wants (in this case point, line or bar) via a drop down menu. Then he clicks on the button on the bottom of the Userform. The following code should run and copy the desired graph.

So far the following code has not worked, but I cant figure out why.

```
Private Sub BTN1_Click()

Select Case .True

    Case SelectGraph = Point
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").ChartObjects(1).Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("F4")
    
    Case SelectGraph = Bar
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").ChartObjects(2).Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("F4")

    Case SelectGraph = Line
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").ChartObjects(3).Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("F4")

End Sub
```

Also open to alternatives.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top of your code and you will get your answer. What are the values of `SelectGraph` , `Point`, `Bar` etc.

Comment: Strange `Select Case`-Syntax, btw. Why don't you use `Select Case SelectGraph`?

Comment: SelectGraph is the drop down menu. Point, Bar and Line are options one can choose.

Comment: Yes that is what you know but how will the code know what are those?

Comment: Using Select Case SelectGraph there are no more Error Messages. But the desired graph does not appear and the UserForm does not close.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`. You will most likely get a compiler-message that `Point` is undeclared. What you probably mean is `"Point"`. Same for the other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
Private Sub BTN1_Click()
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    Select Case SelectGraph
        Case "Point": n = 1
        Case "Bar": n = 2
        Case "Line": n = 3
    End Select
    
    If n > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Tabelle2").ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy
        With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
            .Paste Destination:=.Range("F4")
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```